# Creating AnimationDrawable from assets

Tags: android

I locate several .png files (frames of my animation) in `assets` folder, than I fetch them using `AssetManager` in my `Activity`'s `onCreate()` method and fill my `AnimationDrawable` with them. As described in dev guide it's impossible to start Animation in `onCreate()` method and if I need to start it immediately than I should override `onWindowFocusChanged()` method. But even in such implementation my drawable object doesn't appears on the screen. Here is the code of my Activity:

```
package org.example.Animation;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private LinearLayout ll;
    private ImageView image;
    private AnimationDrawable ad;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ll = new LinearLayout(this);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(-2, -2);
        image = new ImageView(this);
        ll.addView(image, lp);
        setContentView(ll);


        AssetManager am = getAssets();
        ad = new AnimationDrawable();
        StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder("loader/loader-");

        // Fetching frames from assets
        for(int i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
            sb.append(i);
            sb.append(".png");
            Log.d("DownloadImageTask", "Fetching image: " + sb.toString());         
            try {
                Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(am.open(sb.toString()), null);
                ad.addFrame(d, 500);                                        
            } 
            catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d("ImageViewAdapter", "IOException: " + e.getMessage());
            }
            sb.delete(14, sb.length()); // 14 - is the index of first digit of frame
        }

        image.setBackgroundDrawable(ad);                            
    }

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {        
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        ad.start();
    }
}
```

Tell me please what is wrong in my code?

**P.S**
Please, don't ask me why I'm not using xml file. In shorts my main goal is to avoid uisng of R.java file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Waiting for a long time, found solution myself thanks to [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=14863). Just need to change values of View's widht and height to **fixed** or to **FILL_PARRENT**

Answer (score 0):

Frame by frame animation load from images in assets folder
[click here](http://www.ssaurel.com/blog/learn-to-make-a-frame-animation-with-a-character-sprite-in-android/)

Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45647381/2902830